# 3ds max plugin for IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, 3dsmax

We made some models using the 3ds max,now we want to put these models in the web page,I wonder if there is any way to implement this?

I have googled '3ds max plugin IE',but I can not get any useful information.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The unity 3d game engine will do this.
Export from 3ds max, import in unity then publish for the web.

http://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this "directly" from 3dsmax.

you have to export to a web enabled engine.

There are many engines like that, some examples:

http://www.dxstudio.com/

http://emma3d.sourceforge.net/

http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/

Answer (score 0):

Hedphelym is correct in that 3ds max is not a distribution format for 3D on the web. For the most part, you need a plugin to display 3D in a webpage.

The safest way to do this would be to export to Collada and use Papervision3D. I say this is the safest because for the user, it only requires that they have Flash installed. Realistically, only a tiny number of your site's viewers are going to be willing to install another plugin just to see 3D models on your site.

The problem is that Autodesk's Collada exporter exports data in a way that Papervision3D doesn't expect. You'll need to use the [OpenCollada exporter](http://www.opencollada.org/download.html). Which is not available for 3ds max 2012, so hopefully you have an install of 2011 lying around.

Answer (score 0):

3D Studio Max is just a modeling application, it doesn't provide a 3D web engine. I agree with all the answers below, especially PaperVision3D. However, it's clunky and not attractive at all.

Adobe released a while back Flash Player 11, which features Stage3D, a very advanced 3D API. Its level of detail is somewhere around DirectX 8.

To use it, you will need a 3D web engine, like [Alternativa3D](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/technologies/alternativa3d/).